# How do I implement a Graphics class in my main loop?

Tags: java, graphics

I've written a simulation in Java, and, with help, got a class that extends JPanel. A summary of the implementation is as follows:

```
public class Map extends JPanel {
BufferedImage truck1;

public Map() throws IOException {
    truck1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Truck.png"));
}

protected void paintcomponent (Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(truck1, 50, 100, 300, 300, this);
}
```

How do I go about initializing or calling this object in my main function, to make it draw the objects on screen?

Answer (score 1):

How about using google: [Swing tutorial](http://www.java-tutorial.org/jframe.html)

1. Create a JFrame
2. add your JPanel to it
3. make the frame visible